# Keyboard shortcut to show all workspaces in Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, workspaces

What is the keyboard shortcut in Gnome (on Debian jessie) for showing all the workspaces in one window? Something like `super-W` in Ubuntu.

Comment: The distribution isn't relevant. What's relevant is the desktop environment. What desktop environment are you using on Debian?

Comment: im using Gnome desktop